# Why does mpi4py scatter not work as expected for integer array?

Tags: python, mpi4py

I was debugging an mpi4py script and the problem turned out to be an integer array not scattering as I expected. It works when I cast the array as floats but I was wondering why it doesn't work for integers so I can avoid the problem in future.

Running the following with 4 processes:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = comm.Get_size()
    rank = comm.Get_rank()

    x = None
    y = None
    parts_per_proc = 3

    if rank == 0:
        x = np.arange(0,size*parts_per_proc, dtype='float64')
        y = np.arange(0, size*parts_per_proc, dtype='int')

    x_proc = np.zeros(parts_per_proc)
    y_proc = np.zeros(parts_per_proc)

    comm.Scatter(x, x_proc, root=0)
    comm.Scatter(y, y_proc, root=0)

    print(f"process {rank}, x_full: {x}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, x_proc: {x_proc}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, y_full: {y}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, y_proc: {y_proc}", flush=True)
```

Then I get the output:

```
 process 1, x_full: None
 process 2, x_full: None
 process 3, x_full: None
 process 0, x_full: [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11.]
 process 0, x_proc: [0. 1. 2.]
 process 0, y_full: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
 process 0, y_proc: [0.e+000 5.e-324 1.e-323]
 process 1, x_proc: [3. 4. 5.]
 process 1, y_full: None
 process 1, y_proc: [1.5e-323 2.0e-323 2.5e-323]
 process 2, x_proc: [6. 7. 8.]
 process 2, y_full: None
 process 2, y_proc: [3.0e-323 3.5e-323 4.0e-323]
 process 3, x_proc: [ 9. 10. 11.]
 process 3, y_full: None
 process 3, y_proc: [4.4e-323 4.9e-323 5.4e-323]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I answered my own question; I guess its obvious once you think about it but I spent the morning scratching my head and only once I post it here I notice the obvious...

The arrays you're scattering to have to be cast to the same type as the scattered from array. Maybe I'm naive but it seems an odd way to silently fail to fill it with tiny numbers instead of raising an error and not very duck-type to be unable to interpret an integer as a float but I least I understand why now!

Running:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = comm.Get_size()
    rank = comm.Get_rank()

    x = None
    y = None
    parts_per_proc = 3

    if rank == 0:
        x = np.arange(0,size*parts_per_proc, dtype='float64')
        y = np.arange(0, size*parts_per_proc, dtype='int')

    x_proc = np.zeros(parts_per_proc)
    y_proc = np.zeros(parts_per_proc, dtype=int)

    comm.Scatter(x, x_proc, root=0)
    comm.Scatter(y, y_proc, root=0)

    print(f"process {rank}, x_full: {x}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, x_proc: {x_proc}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, y_full: {y}", flush=True)
    print(f"process {rank}, y_proc: {y_proc}", flush=True)
```

Gets the output

```
process 1, x_full: None
process 2, x_full: None
process 2, x_proc: [6. 7. 8.]
process 2, y_full: None
process 2, y_proc: [6 7 8]
process 3, x_full: None
process 3, x_proc: [ 9. 10. 11.]
process 3, y_full: None
process 3, y_proc: [ 9 10 11]
process 1, x_proc: [3. 4. 5.]
process 1, y_full: None
process 1, y_proc: [3 4 5]
process 0, x_full: [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11.]
process 0, x_proc: [0. 1. 2.]
process 0, y_full: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
process 0, y_proc: [0 1 2]
```